# Symfony Dom Crawler Array Push Each

Tags: arrays, symfony, domcrawler

I am stumped by this one. I'm using Symfony's Dom crawler to filter some  elements before extracting node data to push into array that can be converted to json. Yet the code below throws up a "Uncaught TypeError: array_push(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array" error.

```
    if($query == 'begin') {
      $persons = $crawler->filter('#content > table > tr > td > a');
        $trial = [];
            $persons->each(function (Crawler $node) {

                $holder['name'] = $node->text();
                $holder['url'] = $node->attr('href');
                print_r($holder['name']);
                // Correct value printed
                print_r($holder['url']);
                // Correct value printed
;               array_push($trial, $holder);

    });    
    var_dump($trial);
```

print_r shows the expected key-value yet the $trail array is null.

Yet the correct values are given when I try:

```
$persons->each(function (Crawler $node) {
                    echo "<div class='col col-lg-3'>
                            <a href='{$node->attr('href')}'>{$node->text()}</a>   
                          </div>";
                });
```

Comment: What if you do `function (Crawler $node) use $trial` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue was with returning the values on the foreach loop. Managed to solve it with the code below:

```
if($query == 'begin') {
    
  $trial = [];

  $persons = $crawler->filter('#content > table > tr > td > a');

  $trial = $persons->each(function (Crawler $node)  {

    $holder['name'] = $node->text();
    $holder['url'] = $node->attr('href');

    return $holder;

});
```

Hat-tip to this thread - https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/issues/266

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are in variable scope. Function **each** have own local scope. Variable `$trial` is in local scope of upper function. There are two different local scopes, that is a reason why you can not "see" this variable.

```
      $persons = $crawler->filter('#content > table > tr > td > a');
      $holders = $persons->each(function (Crawler $node) {

                $holder['name'] = $node->text();
                $holder['url']  = $node->attr('href');
                
                return $result[$holder['name']] = $holder['url'];
       });
```